# Changing the input area for touch pad

Tags: touchpad

I have a HP ENVY 17 laptop with a touch pad that whose 'touch input area' includes the left and right click buttons. The problem I have with this is that when I go to click the left button it tends to move the pointer across the screen and I miss the click. Is there any way to update the touch area to not include the bottom quarter inch?

Comment: Well I searched around some more today and looks like I should look into gpointed (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gpointing-device-settings). I will try it out after work and see if that helps.

Comment: Nope that didn't seem to have settings for this.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the HP Envy series touchpads, however, if the touchpad is a Clickpad (like MacBook Pro where the whole surface is also a button). You could run the following command in the terminal to see properties of the touchpad:

```
xinput list-props <device id>
```

where `<device id>` is the "device id" of your mouse, you can find it by running `xinput list`.

To change properties you should run:

```
xinput set-prop <device id> <property> <value>
```

If HP uses Synaptics touchpads, [this page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man4/synaptics.4.html) explains all the listed properties from `xinput list`.

Let me know if this helps.